# Does wpa_supplicant support WiFi Direct?

Tags: linux, wifi, wireless, android-networking, wpa

i need to access wifi direct channel to get more information about group ex: RSSI  cab we do this by using wpa_supplicant???

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can use wpa_supplicant v1.1 or above(preferably v2.0) to use wifi-direct(p2p) commands.

See [this](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/hostapd-wps/wpa_supplicant/README-P2P?rev=16495) and [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts).

Comment: can i add this package to android source then have new ROM that have "wpa_supplicant" then can i access Wifi direct through wpa's package ??

Comment: is this doable with android devices ? or need some spacial interfaces ?

Comment: for android(v4.0 and above) the WiFi direct feature in-built.There you dont need to use the p2p_commands.You can develop application using APIs (or use sample programs provided).See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) from android developers site.

Comment: but the Wifi Direct API doesn't offer the feature to measure the received signal strength (RSSI) between peers ???
this feature doesn't implement yet !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **p2p_peer** command on control interface of p2p to get the info regarding p2p_peer. For your case if you need signal strength, check **level** in returned value of p2p_peer command.